# How this if statement works in C. I know what it does but I can't brake it in pieces

Tags: c, gdk

I'm struggling to understand how this if statement works:

```
if (keyval == GDK_PLUS &&
    (event->state & ~consumed & ALL_ACCELS_MASK) == GDK_CONTROL_MASK)
```

founded here https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Keyboard-Handling.html#gdk-keymap-translate-keyboard-state

Full example code:

```
#define ALL_ACCELS_MASK (GDK_CONTROL_MASK | GDK_SHIFT_MASK | GDK_MOD1_MASK)

gdk_keymap_translate_keyboard_state (keymap, event->hardware_keycode,
                                     event->state, event->group,
                                     &keyval, NULL, NULL, &consumed);

if (keyval == GDK_PLUS &&
    (event->state & ~consumed & ALL_ACCELS_MASK) == GDK_CONTROL_MASK)
    // Control was pressed
```

My objective is to understand it so I can port it to Vala since the example given in [Valadocs](https://valadoc.org/gdk-3.0/Gdk.Keymap.translate_keyboard_state.html) is the same written here in C, and not in Vala.

Comment: is the binary `&` operator left associative ? Is it even communitative? You could look this up.

Comment: @Otavio Pliger It is the logical AND ioerator

Comment: That's some very odd code. You don't normally see `&` chained like that.

Comment: @tadman You do when you’re combining bitmasks; here it looks like there’s an additional mask indicating what’s currently "valid".

Comment: @DaveNewton That's what they're doing, but it does look odd to have an intermediate mask.

Comment: @tadman ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Dunno. It's a little strange because it seems like you could just & with the desired mask but I'd have to actually think about it :/

Comment: @DaveNewton Yeah, that's the thing. You see chained `|` (or) a lot, but rarely do you ever see `&` piled on like that. Probably because there's a better way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### First part

```
keyval == GDK_PLUS
```

This does exactly what it appears -- checks if `keyval` is equal to `GDK_PLUS`.

---

### Second part

Let's work outwards.

```
~consumed
```

This is a *bitwise not*. It inverts the bits individually.

`00101100` → Bitwise not → `11010011`

```
(event->state & ~consumed & ALL_ACCELS_MASK)
```

`&` is *bitwise and*. It compares the bits in the two operands and sets the bits in the output only if they are both 1. For example,

```
  binary    hex   dec
  11010111  0xD7  215
& 01101101  0x6D  109
=====================
  01000101  0x45  69
```

Putting the full second part together:

```
(event->state & ~consumed & ALL_ACCELS_MASK) == GDK_CONTROL_MASK
```

This checks if the bitwise and of `event->state`, `~consumed`, and `ALL_ACCELS_MASK` is equal to `GDK_CONTROL_MASK`.

---

Add a comment if you want clarification.

Comment: A bit of explanation of what `consumed` does and why it is logically inverted would be nice, i.e. *"Modifiers that affected the translation and are thus unavailable for application use are returned in consumed_modifiers."* [Gdk 3 Reference - keyboard handling](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Keyboard-Handling.html)

Comment: "consumed_modifiers gives modifiers that should be masked out from state when comparing this key press to a hot key. For instance, on a US keyboard, the plus symbol is shifted, so when comparing a key press to a <Control>plus accelerator <Shift> should be masked out." from [here](http://wrapl.sourceforge.net/doc/Gtk/Gdk/Keymap.html)

Comment: I haven't the foggiest idea what this statement is for; I'm just breaking it down into bite-sized pieces for you. If anyone knows what this statement is for, feel free to edit.